Blender camera fbx export does not work correctly
I have a camera animated and baked to keyframes. In Blender scene camera animating smoothly, even after baking. But after exporting as FBX to Cinema 4d, Nuke or 3ds Max, there is the same issue - camera is twitching in some moments. I tried to export as fbx, glb, dae. How to solve the problem? I know only that problem starting from exporting. 

Do you try to import again in Blender, to identify if some information are missing at export, or if they are exported but not understood by other softwares ? Do you identify if something "special" happens during the animation specifically at the frames you are circling in red ?

@StefLAncien I solved the problem! I exported from Blender to After Effects, using IO plugin. In after Effects camera was perfectly smooth as in Blender. Than i exported from After Effects to Cinema 4D.
But I am still in question, why can not to export as fbx to C4D? I dont know where is the , missing issue.
